# Boostrap 3 dropdowns require extra click on mobile?

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.2 drop downs and have multiple in a btn-group

Using a desktop browser if I click to open a dropdown while another is open this closes the first dropdown and opens the second.

On mobile (iOS, multiple devices, 7.1.2 and 8.0, on Safari and Chrome) if I do the same thing it only closes the first dropdown and requires a second click to open the second dropdown.

To reproduce navigate to [the bootstrap website's vertical button group docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-vertical) and try clicking the dropdowns. This isn't limited to btn-groups though just any two dropdowns.

Is this a touch vs mouse thing or am I going nuts?